# Object to object conversion with complex logic

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Let's say we have some object of complex class `Foo` and some branchy type hierarchy, such as:

```
class Bar {}
class BarA:Bar{}
class BarB:Bar{}
class BarC:BarA{}
```

The task is to convert Foo object to one of Bar descendants. We have two sets of rules:

- Rules about which `Bar` descendant we should choose according to `Foo` field values. For example, if `foo.Type == "A"` and `foo.Complex == true` than `foo` should be converted to `BarC` object.
- Rules about how to convert `foo` fields to `BarXXX` fields. For example, if we choose `BarA` as target class, than `foo.Date` should be converted to `barA.DateA`. But if we choose `BarC`, `foo.Date` should be converted to `barC.DateC` and `barC.DateA` should be `DateTime.MinValue`.

I just want to avoid reinventing the wheel and writing spagetti code with tones of conditional logic. I think AutoMapper and ValueInjecter won't help here.
I'm looking for some elegant solution. Any advice please?

Comment: Without providing all of the conditions how would we be able to find some trick or pattern in those conditions that let you do something other than just check them all?

Comment: The question is not to avoid checking conditions, but to find some general approach.

Comment: There is no general case solution that will work regardless of what the conditions are.  If we know what the conditions are it's possible that, for those conditions, there's some other way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to go for an advanced pattern: a simple list of tuples `{predicate, builder}` is sufficient to satisfy your requirements.

Create a list of type `IList<Tuple<Predicate<Foo>,Func<Foo,Bar>>>`, and add pairs of "checkers" and "makers" to it, as follows:

```
private static readonly IList<Tuple<Predicate<Foo>,Func<Foo,Bar>>> CheckersAndMakers =
    new List<Tuple<Predicate<Foo>,Func<Foo,Bar>>>()
{
    new Tuple<Predicate<Foo>,Func<Foo,Bar>>(
        f => f.Type == "A" && f.Complex  // Checker
    ,   f => new BarC {DateC = foo.Date} // Maker
    )
,   new Tuple<Predicate<Foo>,Func<Foo,Bar>>(
        f => f.Type == "C" && !f.Complex  // Checker
    ,   f => new BarA {DateA = DateTime.MinValue} // Maker
    )
};
```

Now you can go through the checkers in a loop, and use its corresponding maker when you have a match:

```
Bar MakeFromFoo(Foo f) {
    foreach (var tuple in CheckersAndMakers) {
        if (tuple.Item1(f)) {
            return tuple.Item2(f);
        }
    }
    throw new ApplicationError("Unrecognized foo");
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you. This is some kind of Policy Pattern, I keep it as emergency exit :)

Comment: @Alina I wouldn't glorify this simple trick with a "pattern" name: essentially, two parallel lists of function pointers make it as flexible as it gets, and put all the mapping logic in one place.